# Tutorial about OpenMap

Tags: java, openmap

I'm looking for tutorial about OpenMap, which is one of map api.
But there is no good tutorial and documentation about this library on their web site. 
I mailed them  about this  subject. But there is no response from them.
If you know any good tutorial can you share it?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the [OpenMap Developer's Guide](http://openmap-java.org/docs/OpenMapDevGuide.pdf) to be quite helpful when I had to maintain an application built on OpenMap.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial from NetBeans might help.

https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-geospatial.html

It shows how to use OpenMap and GeoToolkit.